# Is there any relationship between the Hungarian long s sound and the long s in some European languages?

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, indo-european, history, hungarian

This [History SE question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52097/when-did-f-become-s-why) (with some references), which enquires about when the f (actually an ſ) became an s and why in English specifically, prompted me to wonder if there was any relationship with the Hungarian ssz.

To clarify, **this question is about the long phonetical sound**, as in an exaggerated ssssss sound, rather than the grapheme.

What, if any, is the relationship between e.g. the English long s (ſ) or the German long s (ß), and the Hungarian long s (ssz, which is actually short for szsz and hyphenated as sz-sz)? Does the Hungarian ssz sound (see e.g. [vissza](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vissza), vs the short sz in [viszlát](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viszl%C3%A1t)) predate the Magyar departure from the Ural region, or is it a loan sound that the Magyars picked up along the way or after settling in Europe?

Comment: English does not have a long s sound, but the sound s can be spelled s or ss, depending. English speakers might hiss "ssss" for some reason but that is not part of the language.

Comment: @user6726: that's true today, but was it true in, say, when Shakespeare was writing? Also, let me edit the question to make it even clearer that this is absolutely not about English, but rather about the phonetical sound.

Comment: @user6726: For instance, [this article](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/history-of-long-s/) suggests that at one point, it was only used for `ss`, as in `congreſs`, which may very have been pronounced differently then.

Comment: If you don't mean to ask about graphemes, I don't think it makes sense to mention ſ at all.

Comment: In your answer to the [related question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52097/when-did-f-become-s-why), initially youimplicitly treat *ſ* as a letter, then suddenly you say "Anecdotally, Hungarian also has a similar but possibly unrelated sound: ssz", implying that *ſ* is also a 'sound': it is not, as it represents the exact same sound as *s*, and the difference between it and *s* was merely dictated by its position in words. Now, German *ß* (which came about as an *ſz* ligature) might well be the source of the Hungarian digraph *sz*, I don't know.

Comment: Might anyone care to explain why this got two downvotes?

Comment: @LjL: I'm very suspicious that the Hungarian ssz (double sz, hyphenated sz-sz) derives only from German. sumelic raises a list of German loan words in his answer, and I took a quick look at a similar list in French, but there are also plenty of other Hungarian words with a ssz, e.g. vissza, mindössze, összeg, asszony (which might derive from Ossetian), etc. To me this suggests the sound predates the Magyar arrival in Europe.

Comment: @sumelic: Which is kind of the whole point of asking, wouldn't you think? Had I known ſ merely was an anal way of writing s, I wouldn't have bothered asking the question, or even wondering if there were any links between it and phonetically long s sounds.

Comment: @sumelic: your answer is a bit hard to read for a non-specialist, but I eventually got to the end. But TBH my main takeaway is that the English long s has nothing to do with pronunciation, and as I finished reading it I didn't get the impression I was a lot more informed about whether the Hungarian ssz predates the Magyar departure from southern Ural or was a loan word they picked up along the way. To your credit though, my question _is_ unclear, and I probably wouldn't have asked the question that way, or at all, had I know the English long s had nothing to do with pronunciation.

Comment: @sumelic: the question is hopefully clearer like that?

Comment: If you haven't seen them already, you may find it interesting to look at the quotes and links in the following ELU posts about the character ſ: [Use of “f ” instead of “s” in historic, printed English documents](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/37982), [How exactly was the long S used and why did people stop using it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/321980?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I initially downvoted this question for two reasons: (1) the confusion of orthography with phonetics (to a layperson, the distinction between the two is often quite difficult to apprehend) and (2) the erroneous perception that English and German have phonetically long [s:] sounds (a belief that is probably influenced by your knowledge of the languages' orthography).  After your edits, in my opinion the best statement of your question is now basically just your final sentence: whence the Hungarian geminate <ssz> [s:]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't really any connection between the Hungarian "ssz" sound and the spelling ſ or ß.

The question about the origin of ssz in Hungarian is interesting. What I have gathered so far is that ssz in Hungarian is fairly infrequent, and may be disproportionately more frequent in loanwords (where it seems to mostly be derived ultimately from "ss" in Latin or in Romance languages), but it was not introduced to the language by loaning. However, I also am not sure if there are any examples of it being inherited intact from some Uralic geminate consonant: I have the impression that in native words, it would originate from simplification of some other sequences. I need to do more research about this.

Also, as far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be anything particularly special about ssz as compared to other long consonant sounds like tt, kk, or ccs.

To refer to spellings, I'll use the angle-brackets convention, so ⟨s⟩ is a spelling, [s] is a sound, and /s/ is an element of a sound system.

### The spelling ⟨ſ⟩ is not "long" in the sense of phonetic length

The letter-form ⟨ſ⟩, sometimes called "long s", was as far as I know never used to represent a phonetically lengthened s sound.  The term "long" refers to its shape, not its pronunciation: it is vertically elongated. It was used historically as a non-final variant lowercase form of the letter S in the spelling systems of a number of languages. Because of rules about how to write certain kinds of words, like compounds, it occasionally represented a distinct pronunciation from "short/round s" (e.g. in German, a famous example is *Wachſtube* /ˈvaxˌʃtuːbə/ vs. *Wachstube* /ˈvaksˌtuːbə/), but you can see from this example that it was not a matter of a phonetic or phonemic length distinction.

German ⟨ß⟩ is supposed to have originated as a ligature, the first element of which was ⟨ſ⟩. Since German spelling historically used both ⟨ß⟩ and ⟨ſ⟩ as contrastive elements, it's confusing to call ⟨ß⟩ a "German long s". Wikipedia says that [ß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) is called *Eszett* or *scharfes S* in German, and *eszett* or *sharp s* in English.

### Hungarian

Hungarian has a two-way phonological contrast between voiced and voiceless consonants for most obstruents, so /s/ ⟨sz⟩ and /z/ ⟨z⟩ are distinct phonemes.

It also has a distinct phonological contrast between short/basic/single and long/double/geminate consonants, as with [s] ⟨sz⟩ vs. [sː] ⟨ssz⟩. The phonemic analysis of long/geminate consonants in Hungarian seems to be controversial, with some linguists analyzing them as mere sequences (Ham 2001, p. 101). In the rest of this post, I will use the term "geminate" to refer to things like ⟨ssz⟩. Hungarian spelling differentiates geminate ⟨ssz⟩ from doubled ⟨szsz⟩ (the latter is found in compounds) and I read somewhere (sorry, I forget where) that there may be slight differences in pronunciation also between ⟨ssz⟩ and ⟨szsz⟩, but that the realizations overlap.

It seems that just about every consonant in Hungarian can be geminate, although some consonants are more commonly found as geminates than others. (According to Ham 2001, p. 102, all Hungarian consonants are found geminate except for [h] and [ʒ]. It seems that in fact, geminate /h/ exists, but is realized as [xː]. Geminate /ʒ/ seems to exist in inflected forms, at least, such as *rozzsal* (the instrumental case of *rozs*), even if it doesn't exist in the lemma form of any word.)

No consonant is found very frequently as a geminate: the table of frequencies in  §2.5.1.1 of Grimes 2009 indicates that in dictionary forms, every consonant phoneme is found more than 92% of the time as a single or basic rather than a geminate consonant. Although [zː] seems to be rare, this frequency table indicates that words with [zː] do exist, so we can say that there is a four-way contrast between [s], [sː], [z], [zː].

#### ⟨ssz⟩ in native words

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the sound changes that applied between Proto-Uralic and Hungarian. Here are some words with ⟨ssz⟩ from Wiktionary's list of "[Hungarian terms inherited from Proto-Finno-Ugric](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Hungarian_terms_inherited_from_Proto-Finno-Ugric)", and their etymologies as given by Wiktionary:

- [vessző](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vessz%C5%91#Hungarian) from PFU "*waćɜ"
- [messze](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/messze#Hungarian) from PFU "*mećä"
- [rossz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rossz#Hungarian) from PFU "*roćɜ"

#### "Borrowed consonant lengthening" in Hungarian

I found a PDF by Bálint Huszthy with some relevant information about the occurence of geminate consonants in Hungarian. Not too surprisingly, geminates have restricted distribution compared to single consonants, and in native vocabulary geminates are rare and have a low contrastive load with singleton consonants. Because of this, geminates may have a role in Hungarian as a characteristic element of "foreign vocabulary". It seems to be debated to what extent gemination in foreign vocabulary is related to the influence of German dialects specifically. Huszthy says that Nádasdy (1989) suggested borrowing from German dialects with gemination led to analogical extension of gemination to other foreign words. But Huszthy (2016) says that "There must be other motivations of ["borrowed consonant lengthening"] beyond language contact" and suggests that it is related to constraints about prosodic structure.

This phenomenon in Hungarian reminds me a bit of how Japanese often has geminate consonants in loanwords, e.g. *Bahha* from German *Bach* or *kyappu* from English *cap.*

#### ⟨ssz⟩ doesn't seem to be too special compared to other geminate consonants

Huszthy does not indicate any special status for ⟨ssz⟩ as opposed to other geminate consonants. The PDF includes a number of examples with geminate consonants other than ⟨ssz⟩:  both ones where the doubling might be taken at least in part from the spelling used in the source language ("desszert, gleccser, hobbi, koffer, kollázs") and ones where the doubling is not present in the spelling of the source language ("dajjer, dopping, maffia, Guttenberg,
vikkendház").

Apparently, voiced fricatives are rarely found geminate, whether in native vocabulary or in loanwords (Magyar 2016, p. 290).

#### Hungarian ⟨ssz⟩ in words from German seems to correspond to ⟨ss⟩, not ⟨ß⟩

I looked through Wiktionary's list of [Hungarian terms derived from German](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Hungarian_terms_derived_from_German). All of the words in this category with ⟨ssz⟩ in Hungarian seemed to be derived from German terms spelled with ⟨ss⟩, not ones spelled with ⟨ß⟩. A number of the examples seem to be Latinate (e.g. *szecesszió, agresszió, asszisztens, asszociativitás*) so influence from some kind of Latin seems somewhat plausible to me (either from Latin spelling, or from some tradition of Latin pronunciation that maintained distinctly long consonant sounds in this kind of context).

### German

#### Standard German does not have phonemically "long" consonant sounds

The usual linguistic description of Standard German does not include any length contrasts for consonant sounds. Instead, Standard German is described as having a two-way contrast for obstruent consonant sounds where one consonant is "lenis" or "voiced" and the other consonant is "fortis" or "voiceless" (I think it may still be disputed whether voice is a relevant phonemic characteristic in the German consonant system, but I'm not sure).

I've read that "lenis"/"voiced" fricatives tend to be phonetically shorter in duration than "fortis/"voiceless" fricatives, but this difference in phonetic duration is not treated as a phonemic length contrast in standard German.

I'm most familiar with the two-way obstruent distinction being represented in phonemic transcriptions of Standard German by the use of IPA symbols for voiced vs. voiceless consonants: that is, /s/ is used to represent the fortis sibilant fricative, and /z/ is used to represent the lenis sibilant fricative, even though it is not supposed to be uncommon for German /z/ to be phonetically voiceless (at least partially). Standard German is described as having a process of "Auslautverhärtung" that applies to word-final (or syllable-final) obstruents and causes the contrast between lenis and fortis obstruents to be neutralized in perception in favor of fortis obstruents. That means word-final /z/ is supposed to be fortited, causing it to sound like /s/; likewise, word-final /d/ is supposed to be fortited, causing it to sound like /t/. I've read papers that suggest that this kind of [neutralization may be incomplete in production](http://www.bodowinter.com/papers/winter_rottger_IN_grazer.pdf).

Consonant sequences like /s.z/ may occur across syllable boundaries, but such a sequence is not considered to constitute a phonologically long or geminate consonant (compare how in English, /s.s/ can occur across syllable boundaries in compounds like 'housesitting", but English is not usually described as having geminate consonants in its inventory of consonant sounds).

#### Consonant length in historical and dialectal varieties of German

There are supposed to be dialects of German that do have phonemic length contrasts, but I don't know enough to summarize the situation. As mentioned above, it seems to be thought that dialects like this may have been the source of some Hungarian words with geminate consonants (not just ⟨ssz⟩ specifically, but also other geminates).

From a historical perspective, German ⟨ß⟩ mostly represents older /t/, via the "[High German consonant shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_German_consonant_shift)". In German, the inherited /t/ sound is supposed to have developed in many contexts to a long fricative with an s-like quality; the linked Wikipedia article says that it has been suggested that it was specifically a laminal voiceless sibilant. The resulting sound in modern standard German is standardly transcribed /s/, and spelled ⟨ss⟩ after short vowels, and ⟨ß⟩ after long vowels or diphthongs (in older spelling systems, the grapheme ⟨ß⟩ was used more widely). I haven't actually found any Hungarian word with ⟨ssz⟩ derived from Germanic /t/, though.

### English

The form  ⟨ſ⟩ was used in English to represent the same sounds as ⟨S⟩ or  ⟨s⟩: mostly /s/ and /z/, in some cases /ʃ/ or /ʒ/ in words with historical palatalization-related sound changes. It's a bit similar to the old use of ⟨v⟩ and ⟨u⟩ as contextual spelling variants (⟨v⟩ at the start of a word, ⟨u⟩ elsewhere). Spellings like ⟨congreſs⟩ don't tell you anything about the pronunciation: the word might have been pronounced differently in the past, but that's not related to how it was spelled.

English had consonant length a long time ago (consonant length distinctions are uncontroversially reconstructed as being present in Old English, although long consonants had a restricted distribution, and I have the impression that they were fairly infrequent and that the long/short contrast didn't have a very high contrastive load). Long/geminate consonants could be spelled with doubled letters (I don't know how consistent this was), as in *cyssan*  [ˈkysːɑn], the Old English cognate of Modern English *kiss.* Contrastive consonant length in English is thought to have been lost at some point in the Middle English period, which is before Shakespeare's time.

#### References

Grimes, Stephen M. 2009. "[Quantitative Investigations in Hungarian Phonotactics and Syllable Structure](http://pweb.ldc.upenn.edu/%7Esgrimes/papers/diss.pdf)".

Huszthy, Bálint. ["Unmotivated" consonant gemination in the Hungarian Foreign Accent](https://www.academia.edu/33726860/_Unmotivated_consonant_gemination_in_the_Hungarian_Foreign_Accent)

Magyar, Lilla. 2016. "[Are Universal Markedness Hierarchies Learnable from the Lexicon? The Case of Gemination in
Hungarian](http://www.lingref.com/cpp/wccfl/33/paper3248.pdf)".

Ham, William. 2001. *[Phonetic and Phonological Aspects of Geminate Timing](https://books.google.com/books?id=6u9r7rAvNrwC&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q&f=false).*

Comment: The Hungarian ssz is phonetically long. As in (English) sssss. (The German one is too, btw, albeit a lot less pronounced than in Hungarian insofar as I've heard -- I've lived in both countries.)

Comment: I've honestly no idea if it is, which is why I asked. Though to my mind, the German ß is phonetically long, and so is the Hungarian ssz, so I ended up wondering if the latter was borrowed from the former or Latin, or if there was a deeper commonality in a (possibly proto-) Indo European language.

Comment: When you say Süß or Fuß or bißchen or for that matter daß in German, it doesn't sound the same (to my ear anyway) as das. The s is slightly more pronounced, as in lengthier or insistent or with more tone or whatever the correct terminology is. ;-)

Comment: "I also know that Hungarian has had contact with German in the past" -- that's an [understatement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria-Hungary). :) "and there are a number of loans from German, some with sibilant sounds, but I don't think that contact with German is the source of Hungarian "ssz"." Neither do I, and that's precisely why I asked here to confirm (or refute) my hunch.

Comment: I don't know anything about linguistics but I spent some time in Hungary and learned a little bit of Hungarian. About that "low contrastive load", I'm not sure exactly what that means, but what about *tizenegyedik* (11th) and *tizennegyedik* (14th)?

Comment: @user14111: "Low contrastive load" means that there aren't supposed to be many pairs of words where consonant length is the only thing marking the difference in meaning. Your example is a good indication that the contrast is important for some pairs of words. I'm not sure whether the cited claim is supposed to cover words like tizennegyedik where the two n's originate from separate elements. I haven't gotten into it yet in my answer, but some sources distinguish between different kinds of geminates, including "false geminates".

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Your impression that the <ß> in Süß, Fuß, bißchen, daß is different than the <s> in das might be influenced by your knowledge of the orthography.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess the Romance borrowings with geminate consonant are probably at least influenced by Italian, that happens to both be geographically close to Hungary and to have retained the geminate consonants to the present day.

Comment: @DenisNardin: FWIW I found a small collection of Proto-Uralic words that are spelt with ssz today, and possible loan words with the same ssz that long predate the Magyar arrival in Europe. Another data point is the fact is that Estonian and Finnish are also agglutinate languages that germinate consonants. To me it suggests that it's inherent to the language itself. It's not spelt out like that in this answer but there are hints towards that, so I figured I'd accept it if only for the wealth of information in it.

Comment: Great answer.  I think *gleccser* belongs in the other group, it's not doubled in the source language (not can I think of any word with *tschtsch*).

Comment: `Hungarian word with ⟨ssz⟩ derived from Germanic /t/` - It's not really physically possible, at least not from Austrian German directly in Hungarian.  Contact happened after the shift.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer: What I mean is that the ssz would be derived from German [sː] from older Germanic *t

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer: I guess the author was thinking of tsch as a "doubled" spelling by comparison with tz, but it's true that that's a bit dubious since there is no corresponding single spelling, as there is with tz : z.

Comment: Ah, I had misunderstood.